# Print array in Asembly x86

Tags: arrays, assembly, size, cpu-registers

I have elements loaded in stack and I need to move them to array. My code looks like this:

```
%include "asm_io.inc"

segment .data
    array db 100 dup(0)
    length db 0
    
segment .text
    global  _asm_main
    extern getchar

_asm_main:
    enter    0, 0
    pusha

    call getchar
char_loop:
    mov ebx,10
    sub eax, '0'
    mul ebx
    mov ebx, eax
    call getchar
    sub eax, '0'
    add eax, ebx
    push eax
    inc BYTE[length]
    call getchar
    cmp eax, 10
    je fill_array
    cmp eax, 13
    je fill_array
    cmp eax, 32
    je skip_spaces
    jmp char_loop
skip_spaces:
    call getchar
    cmp eax, 32
    je skip_spaces
    jmp char_loop

fill_array:
    mov ecx, [length]
    mov ebx, array
l1:
    pop eax
    mov [ebx], eax ; should be al instead of eax
    inc ebx
    call print_int
    call print_nl
    loop l1
print_array:
    mov ecx, [length]
    mov ebx, array
l2:
    mov eax, [ebx] ; should be al instead of eax
    call print_int
    call print_nl
    inc ebx
    loop l2

_asm_end:
    call print_nl
    popa
    mov eax, 0
    leave
    ret
```

`print_int` in asm_io.asm is

```
print_int:
        enter   0,0
        pusha
        pushf

        push    eax
        push    dword int_format
        call    _printf
        pop     ecx
        pop     ecx

        popf
        popa
        leave
        ret
```

Where `int_format` is `int_format db "%i",0`

Length and values in stack are correct, I had them printed but when I try to print array only last value is correct. Other values are random numbers. I tried combinations of registers of different sizes but it did not work. I think that error has to do something with size of registers or size of array.

Comment: At least, `mov [ebx], eax` should be `mov [ebx], al`, but if your data section has nothing else than `array`, the result will be the same because x86 is little endian. You have to show more of your code, especially how the values are stored in the stack.

Comment: I have shown more code I hope it is enough to find error

Comment: I have made mistake in description of printing of array. It correct print only last element, not first. Note: edited

Comment: I can't say anything for sure if you have to keep important parts of your code secret, but I think you are reading 4 bytes to print while the array's unit is a byte. Seeing that you used `getchar` for input, you might be using `putchar` or `printf` for output, both of which read 4 bytes.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was enough I revealed all code

Comment: Yes, you are reading (printing) 4 bytes while writing (storing) 1 byte at a time.

Comment: And how can I fix that? I have tried pushing and popping AX instead EAX, change array from DB to DW and increment EBX by 2. I think I would need explanation.

Comment: I got it, I understand now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer here:
As @xiver77 said in comments I was writing into array 4 bytes instead 1 byte. One element in array has 1 byte and I tried to write 4 bytes. That creates overflow of bites and change other elements in array.  Instead `mov [ebx], eax` should be `mov [ebx], al` and `mov eax, [ebx]` for printing should be `mov al [ebx]`.